# Overriding methods in java using super

Tags: java, overloading, super, overriding

So, I have to create 68 different summing methods using the datatypes, int, float, double and short. The class is called, OverloadingSums. Here is an example of one the methods.

```
public double sum(double x, float y, int z)
{
    return x+y+z;
}
```

Now I'm being asked to create a class called ZeroSum, essentially copying OverloadingSum and returning everything to zero. Here is an example.

```
public double sum(double x, float y, int z)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then I'm being asked to create another class called RealSum, which will extend the ZeroSum class. I'm a little confused about the wording of this assignment, not sure if the stackoverflow community could help but I'm just extremly confused.

Here is the assignment requirements:

> Now that we have thoroughly explored overloading we are going to
>   explore overriding. Create a class called ZeroSum.java. Take all of
>   the methods from OverloadingSum.java and change them to return all
>   zeros in ZeroSum.java. Next, create a class called RealSum.java. This
>   class, RealSum, will extend the ZeroSum class. Having all zeros for
>   our sums isn't very useful. We will need to override the parent, or
>   super class methods to produce real results. Create the necessary
>   methods to override all of those in the ZeroSum.java. When you are
>   done run your classes against DrivingSum.java.

This is what I have in my main method:

```
public class DrivingSum {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    // x + y = 30....yay?
    ZeroSum zero= new ZeroSum();
    RealSum real= new RealSum();

    System.out.println("Calling ZeroSum " + zero.sum(x,y) );
    System.out.println("Calling ZeroSum " + real.sum(x,y) );

}
```

}

So, from how I'm understanding this I wrote the following code:

```
public class ZeroSum extends RealSum{
    public double sum(double x, float y, int z)
    {
        return super.sum(x,y,z);
    }
```

This will grab the method from RealSum, instead of using the sum method located in the ZeroSum class. So when I run the main method, zero.sum(x,y) gives me 30.

The confusion comes from the fact that the assignment asks me to set everything in ZeroSum returning to zero. If I extend ZeroSum to RealSum, it doesn't really make a difference. Am I doing this correctly? or Am I just overthinking this way too much?

Comment: "so, I have to create 68 different summing methods using the datatypes, int, float, double and short" , heard of a thing called `Generics`

Comment: No I haven't, but after googling it I'm pretty sure that's not part of my requirement. I just wanted to know if my logic is correct or not.

Comment: *I'm being asked to create another class called RealSum, which will extend the ZeroSum class* --> You wrote `public class ZeroSum extends RealSum`?

Comment: Btw, I think this assignment is very confusing in general. There are way better examples for teaching overriding and overloading. But that's not your fault of course.

Comment: @Manu Here is where I'm confused at _We will need to override the parent, or super class methods to produce real results_ specifically. Also, this assignment is terribly written, I've asked some of my peers the same questions who were left uncertain like how I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of this assignment is to explore overriding concept, where function executed depends on type of object it called upon on run time, so you will have something like this :

```
public class ZeroSum {
    public double sum(double x, float y)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class RealSum  extends ZeroSum{
    public double sum(double x, float y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }
}

public class DrivingSum {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    // x + y = 30....yay?
    ZeroSum zero= new ZeroSum();
    ZeroSum real= new RealSum();

    System.out.println("Calling ZeroSum " + zero.sum(x,y) ); //here the sum will return zero 
    System.out.println("Calling ZeroSum " + real.sum(x,y) ); //here the sum will return 30 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how I initially wrote the program but somehow doubted myself after thinking too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he's trying to make a point in which whatever you write in the parent class is transferred (this is called inheritage) to the child. You can override this by writing a method in the child class using the same name and arguments as the parent class' method.

I also believe you read the assignment a bit wrong, it said:

> This class, RealSum, will extend the ZeroSum class.

I interpret this as RealSum is the child to ZeroSum, not the other way around as such:

```
public class RealSum extends ZeroSum{
   //code code code
}
```

This means everything in ZeroSum is set to 0 and RealSum set new values, not using the super. I'm not betting my hand this is correct but try to read the assignment again after a break and some fresh air :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I initially did exactly what you wrote, but after reading the part where the assignment states _Having all zeros for our sums isn't very useful._ I kept thinking maybe they want us to have it so that when zero.sum is called, it won't return zero. Maybe I'm overthinking it, thanks for the input.

Comment: Ask your instructor to clarify what he means? He'd probably appreciate you asking, it shows interest in the assignment and solving it.